# How to match 2 substrings in responce with regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex, load-testing

I have a responce string

`"c=2020&#038;action=approvecomment&#038;_wpnonce=7508ac918a' data-wp-lists='dim:the-comment-list:comment-2020:unapproved:e7e7d3:e7e7d3:new=approved"`

Im trying to extract `2020` and `7508ac918a`. I dont understand how I must use regex with substrings in C#, simple regex like

`c=(\d+)&#038;action=approvecomment&#038;_wpnonce=(.*?)' .+new=approved.`

Answer (score 0):

In Regex, you can create match groups 
They look like this (?.+?) 
So your _wpconce part could become something like this (?.*?)

Then you can grab each group individually for example

```
 Match result = myRegex.Match(someString);
 soneOtherString = result.Groups["GROUPNAME"].Value;
```

I use Regex101 to build and test my regex. (Whoever made that site deserves a crown with shinny stones on it!! :)
https://regex101.com/

Hope this helps